# Как вывести логин и ip в оповещении zabbix от event viewer(windows)

Tags: windows, zabbix

У меня есть триггер, который срабатывает на вход в систему и записывает лог в zabbix.

```
{ServerName:eventlog[Security,,,,4634|4625|4672|4798|4624|4648|4776].logeventid(4624)}=1
```

После срабатывания он выводит сообщение, которое можно задать самому.
Как можно настроить вывод и оповещение так, чтобы он выдергивал из eventlog ip и имя аккаунта под которым вошли.
Примерно так.

```
An {username} was successfully logged on. {ip}
```